# SQL Server 2016 - ColumnStore and Fetch

Tags: sql, sql-server, fetch, columnstore

Here is my issue, I have a SQL Server 2016 table with around 5,000,000 rows, it has a clustered columnstore index.

The following query runs in milliseconds:

```
SELECT * FROM Table Extent1
WHERE ([Extent1].[CustomerIden] = '0070db55-6c30-415c-8146-20f43c870107')
AND ([Extent1].[StartTime] <= '2015-02-17 08:54:35')
ORDER BY [Extent1].[StartTime] DESC
```

Adding "OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY" to the end, example:

```
SELECT * FROM Table Extent1
WHERE ([Extent1].[CustomerIden] = '0070db55-6c30-415c-8146-20f43c870107')
AND ([Extent1].[StartTime] <= '2015-02-17 08:54:35')
ORDER BY [Extent1].[StartTime] DESC 
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

takes minutes to run, we identified the issue is that there are not 20 rows returned by the query, if we change the query to

```
SELECT * FROM Table Extent1
WHERE ([Extent1].[CustomerIden] = '0070db55-6c30-415c-8146-20f43c870107')
AND ([Extent1].[StartTime] <= '2015-02-17 08:54:35')
ORDER BY [Extent1].[StartTime] DESC 
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

it once again executes in milliseconds.

Any idea on how to overcome this without having to do a count first in order to manually set the `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT` values?

Comment: *FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY* will never return more than 20 records AFAIK

Comment: `SELECT FROM` -- select what? `SELECT *`? Is there a rowstore index on `StartTime`? Columnstore indexes aren't generally suitable for seeks like this, especially not if all columns need to be retrieved.

Comment: Post actual execution plans.

Comment: @Prdp, you are not understanding the problem 100%, the issue is that if there are less that 20 rows, the query takes a LONG time.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You are correct, for some reason the * didn't paste (I will update the post), No there is not a RowStore index, I was trying to get away without using one. The query without the "OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY" returns data immediately.

Comment: To clarify the query itself runs in milliseconds, the issue is ONLY when "OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY" is added to a query that returns less that 10 rows.

Comment: Well, of course -- the engine can't *know* there are less than 10 rows, so it will just happily keep on scanning for "the rest", not knowing there is no rest. You specified you want 10 rows, so by golly, it's going to search until it *gets* you 10 rows. That's a lot more work than grabbing the first N records that are all just sitting together. The only way to alleviate this is with an appropriate index, or by artificially constraining your query range (as in, give a lower bound for `StartTime` that's fairly close to the upper bound).

Comment: Oh, but since we *have* a CS index, what might also work is constraining your `FETCH NEXT` explicitly to `MIN(10, COUNT(*))`. I know you said you didn't want to do a `COUNT` first, but then that *is* the sort of thing a CS index is really good at. You could conceivably do this in a single query (with a `ROW_NUMBER` or a subquery), but from the shape I'm guessing you might be using Entity Framework and can't easily squeeze that in.

Comment: One more potential solution: stop fetching rows after, say, 1 second, concluding that surely we will have the `TOP smallnumber` rows by now or everything there is if we don't have `smallnumber`. (I previously suggested canceling the query, but there's no need for drastic measures like that -- it's perfectly legal to stop reading rows and end the command that way.) This may be good enough if the query's just supposed to show "something" for a front end, but is obviously flaky if your DB one day just happens to take a bit longer than usual.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks, so what you are suggesting to sum up is to manually set the FETCH NEXT value based on the number of rows returned in a count of the same data? It seems to work in my tests. Our DB sizes are getting large and the number of rowstore indexes is making the DBs really large AND slow on inserts. The clustered columnstore seems to work VERY well, with this small exception. Also important to note is our rows hardly ever get updated after insert, new records are simply added.

Comment: Yes, counting first is one solution. It would fail if rows are ever deleted after the count but before getting them, but that doesn't seem to be a risk in your setup. Note that my initial suggestion was *a* rowstore index -- you might not need more than one if, say, all queries involve a date range in addition to whatever else they need, as this would allow SQL Server to perform a (ranged) index scan rather than a full table scan. Certainly, inserting in a CS index is even slower in general -- you just notice it less because you only need one of them.